# Rename User profile and folders Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles

I'm trying to rename my `User` profile on a fresh Windows10 install.

I've followed these instructions:
 [Renaming a User Account Does Not Automatically Change The Profile Path](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path)

However, I lose my Desktop, Startup settings (`AppData`?), `OneDrive` integration  and the Windows Apps don't seem to work fully and perhaps less obvious things as well, so it hasn't happened properly.

I'm getting this:

[image: error window].

Is there something I'm doing wrong?